# Understanding android.graphics.path and comparing android.graphics.path values

Tags: android

I am working on an application in Android, wherein I have to get android.graphics.[path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) values and compare them.

Consider the following images :

[image]

and

[image]

The first image shows a straight line and the generated Path value. Similarly, the second image,also shows a similar straight line, with a different Path value.

I'm unable to understand the value that is generated. Can anyone explain as to what exactly the generated values mean? Can I approximately take a wild guess about a path value from the screen coordinates?

Also, in my application, I would like to compare path values. The lines shown in the above figure are similar. And in my application, I would like to compare them and render them as same lines. And I'm not just going to compare lines, there'll be curves and all such drawable shapes. For comparison do I first have to normalize my path values (maybe calling [getMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getMatrix%28%29) for my current canvas?), so as to have the same effect for different screen sizes?

There is one other way of comparison that will be much simpler,finding centroids of the paths of figures. Obviously lines will have a centroid at a different position compared to curves,etc. But this sort of comparison won't be so accurate. I wanted to store some value and then compare the generated path value to the stored value, along with comparing the centroids, so as to have a better accuracy. But for that, I need to understand the generated path values!

Please help or guide! Thanks! :-)

**Edit:**

The code that I'm using for converting my path values to String. My path values are stored in an `ArrayList` (called `pointsToDraw` ). Here's the code :

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        synchronized(pointsToDraw){
                        for(Path path : pointsToDraw)
                        {
                            stringPoints.add(String.valueOf(path));
                        }
                        }
                        TextView b1Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GText);
                        for(String s : stringPoints)
                        {
                            b1Text.setText(s);
                        }

            }
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the first part of this question; specifically, what you mean by "the value that is generated". What is the string being shown on the string - is it a result of path.toString()?

Comment: @TrevorPage No. I'm using `String.valueof(path)`. I'll just edit the question and add the code that I'm using to generate the string.

Comment: Isn't that just the way you see the path as it doesn't have an actualy string value, or a `toString()` function? It just says "well, this is an object of android.graphics.Path, and it is currently at memory address blahblahbalh" ?

Comment: `String.valueOf()` actually gives you the result of `.toString()` on the object (as long as the obect is not `null`), where the number after the @ is a hash of the object. My understanding is that what you want to do is identify similarity between `Path`s (which look to be generated from gestures). I don't think comparing the object hashes returned from `.toString()` is going to be of any use to you here, but it's an interesting question to watch.

Comment: @Nanne Even I had read somewhere that I can't actually find out the exact value of android.graphics.Path ( rather the String equivalent ), but then coming to the second part of my question, I need to compare Path values. The base value is stored during training of the application, and then later on, the new generated values are compared to this base value, and the results are returned.

Comment: See my answer: it's not really the "path value". I don't know if there's anything like that, but this is just a value for the `Object`. Don't use it for anything like recognizing how a line is drawn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `Path` object is an object that encapsulates a series of geometric paths. If you want to programmatically compare one path to another, then the place I think you have to start is to use `PathMeasure` on that `Path` object in order to pull out all of the co-ordinates. Using `PathMeasure` you can obtain a series of co-ordinates that the path follows, by supplying a distance argument.

[PathMeasure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PathMeasure.html)

Then, in order to determine whether one given path is *similar* to another in terms of the size and its path along the screen, I would perhaps suggest using `PathMeasure` on them both and comparing the co-ordinates they produce given incremental distance arguments. Then use some comparison algorithm, which may be as simple as determining whether each set of compared co-ordinates are within a distance from each other (with relative starting co-ordinates taken into account).

So I can't help with the algorithm you would use, but as a starting point, I think it's `PathMeasure` that you have to use in order to inspect and analyse the data within the `Path` to begin with. Or, you might want to render them to `bitmap` and use some kind of image recognition library to compare those bitmaps, perhaps?

Comment: I think this is what I need to use! I'll work with this and get back to you incase I successfully have managed to achieve what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really make a string for that object I think, so you get the default value: If you check out [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)  you see that it is actually the same as

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

or, in their words,

> The unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

It's just a hashed value of the object, and has no direct recognisable connection to for instance any features of the Path (location etc). If you really want to know how it is made you can find the `hashCode()` function of that object, but I suspect you won't see anything interesting for this question.

To be clear, when you say you want to compare "path values" you seem to imply that you want to compare above printed values. I don't see how you would want to need that. You probably want to check if 2 separately drawn/created lines are the same. You cannot use this hash for that purpose, you need to use the actual values  like start/stop/angle/or something like that. (I'm not sure what members are present in a path, but you can look that up)

Comment: I get your point. I was going wrong about the way on comparing lines. Exactly what you've written - I want to check if 2 separately drawn/created lines are the same. But I would need some guidance regarding that. I did check the [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) API, I didn't find something useful for my purpose.